# How do I install GNUHealth?

Tags: python, tryton

I am following the installation steps mentioned below but have encountered a python problem.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation#Installing_GNU_Health_on_GNU/Linux_and_FreeBSD

At the step where the initialisation of the database instance is to be performed, I have encountered the following error after executing the following command.

`python3 ./trytond-admin --all --database=health`

**Error encountered:**

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trytond-admin", line 21, in <module>
    admin.run(options)
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-4.6.18/trytond/admin.py", line 24, in run
    with Transaction().start(db_name, 0, _nocache=True):
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-4.6.18/trytond/transaction.py", line 88, in start
    database = Database(database_name).connect()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-4.6.18/trytond/backend/postgresql/database.py", line 97, in __new__
    **cls._connection_params(name))
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py", line 161, in __init__
    self, minconn, maxconn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py", line 62, in _connect
    conn = psycopg2.connect(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Can anyone help me out with this error or tell me what I am missing? 

Based on the error, I suspect that there's a difficulty in connecting to the DB as there is no password specified.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not configured the URI with the credentials to connect to the database. You can find the description of the configuration file at http://docs.tryton.org/projects/server/en/latest/topics/configuration.html#uri
Once you have a configuration file, you must run the command like this:

`python3 ./trytond-admin --all --database=health -c /path/to/trytond.conf`

Comment: Ahhh,..nice. Thank you for your advice.